# Using PHP Get function to show content on webpage, yet still using same PHP file?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, and just creating a simple website.

At the moment, I have a header with some links (i.e. blog, faq, home, gaming etc). I'm trying to use GET functions to show new content in a container on the webpage. I've tried having them link to the index and to a specific page, like

```
<a href="?page=home">Home</a>
```

and then having some PHP in the html body...

```
<?php
if ($_GET[page] == "faq") {
   $result === 'FAQ';
} else {
$result === 'Non-FAQ';
}
echo $result;
?>
```

just to see if it would work, and lo and behold, it doesn't.

So, that's basically the gist of what's happening. It's baffled me for the past few hours, and would really appreciate some help

Thanks

Comment: page should be in quotes (`$_GET["page"]`).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the assignment operator to assign a value to `$result`. Use a single equals sign, ie

```
<?php
if ($_GET['page'] == "faq") {
   $result = 'FAQ';
} else {
   $result = 'Non-FAQ';
}
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: It still isn't working for me, I used that exact example, and even created a new php file and appended ?page=faq to the end, but it still doesn't click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($_GET[page] === "faq") {
   $result = 'FAQ';
} else {
   $result = 'Non-FAQ';
}
echo $result;
?>
```

If you want to DEFINE a string you use one "=", if you want to compare it you use "===" (or ==) :)